# Alloy proper way for tableviewrow color

Tags: styles, tableview, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to set the color of my `TableViewRow` to red ( just for testing ).

The thing is that i create the tablerow dynamically with the following code:

```
$.mainData.appendRow(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: data[i].txt, uid: data[i].uid}));
```

My `app.tss` looks like this:

```
"TableViewRow":{
    color: "#FF0000"
},
".testing": { 
    color: "#FF0000"
}
```

But the color isn't applied to the rows.

I even tried to append the class to the row with this line of code:

```
$.mainData.appendRow(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: data[i].txt, uid: data[i].uid, 'class': 'testing'}));
```

But that also didn't work.

The only way to make it work is like this:

```
$.mainData.appendRow(Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({ title: data[i].txt, uid: data[i].uid, color: "#FF0000"}));
```

But that just doesn't feel like it is the right way. How can i make it work with the `.tss` file like it should work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create style from `.tss` classes. And apply them to the view. More here http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Dynamic_Styles

Comment: Well, I'm not using Titanium anymore (and don't have the project around), so I can't test it. But if you provide some code in your answer I'll mark it as answered because the documentation looks complete...